# why default page open directly when login using asp.net using?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know why default page open directly when login to the website using asp.net not another page in website it was go directly to the home page 
i used (loginStatus control and Login control)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you specify the default page in authentication tag inside web.config.

The default is **default.aspx**. If you want to redirect to a specific page, you can specify in defaultUrl.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="member_login.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl.aspx).

Comment: but i were not use this code before and when run the website go directly to the default after log page why? that tag above very useful to specify which page will go to after login

Comment: If you do not specify ***defaultUrl*** explicitly, user'll be redirected to ***default.aspx*** after successful login. It's written in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.defaulturl.aspx).